# jQuery variable as a selector not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get an option value if clicked, and assign it to variable. Then this variable is called as a part of a selector to hide an element. I'm using this code but it didn't work if I use the variable:

```
     $("#State ul li").live('click', function (event) {
    var currentstate = $(this).children('a').html();

    if ( $(this).hasClass("selected") ) {
        $("#state_"+currentstate).show();
    };

 });
```

I have a `div#state_arizona` with `display: none`, and I want this div to show when the specific state is selected.

If I try the following the div shows without a problem:

```
if ( $(this).hasClass("selected") ) {
$("#state_arizona).show();
};
```

this is the ul html:

```
<ul>
 <li>
     <a href="#" class="ajax-filter-label">
        <span class="checkbox"></span> Alaska </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Any help?

Comment: And what does your HTML look like? The `#State ul` in particular?

Comment: is the text lowercase like the selector string?  Selectors are case sensitive. ALso would use `$.trim( $(this).children('a').text())` so any whitespace is removed as well as any other html

Comment: @DavidThomas I have published the ul HTML.

Comment: @charlietfl  I tried trimming but still no working.

Comment: @DavidThomas sorry, it's above.

Comment: OK... both situations I asked about are true... extra html, so deinitely use `text()` and use `$.trim` due to spaces and also need to use `toLowerCase()`

Comment: when this happens, i'd `console.log(currentstate)` and see what your selector is actually picking up

Comment: Thank you all.
@iight thank you, I missed that. alert(currentstate) returned capitalized name like "Arizona", so I will use toLowerCase().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#State ul li").live('click', function (event) {
    var currentstate = $(this).children('a').text();

    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        $("#state_" + $.trim(currentstate).toLowerCase()).show();
    };
});
```

Notice that the selector by id is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

If you have the ability to restructure your HTML do this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="ajax-filter-label" data-state="alaska">
    <span class="checkbox"></span> Alaska </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Then in your JS you can use .data to get the value of state without wondering what it will look like:

```
$("#state_"+ currentstate.data('state')).show();
```